# Increase Timeouts To Avoid 504 Gateway Timeouts

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger

I've taken over this rails app that is hosted on EC2 using passenger. After 1 minute requests are stopped with a gateway timeout 504 error. Where can this be increased. I've increased apache's `/etc/http/http.conf` to be `TimeOut: 100000000`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: If I were you, I'd try to investigate what's causing those timeouts. And you're trying to mask the problem instead of fixing.

Comment: Good call. I'm am aware and it was a business decision to do this.